# binding onTextChanged for edit text

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to bind edittext `onTextChanged` to the viewmodel.

this is my XML:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="mvvm.f4wzy.com.samplelogin.ui.login.viewmodel.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:onTextChanged="@{viewmodel.onEmailChanged}"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:textColor="#383838"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</layout>
```

LoginViewModel.kt

```
class LoginViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {


    fun onEmailChanged(s: CharSequence) {
        //some code

    }

}
```

kapt gives me an error for on text changed and it says:

> [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot resolve type for viewmodel.onEmailChanged

I have tried `android:onTextChanged="@{(s) -> viewmodel.onEmailChanged}"` and `android:onTextChanged="@{viewmodel::onEmailChanged}"` but still same error.

any help?

Comment: Does it work if you change your invocation to this: `android:onTextChanged="@{(s) -> viewmodel.onEmailChanged(s)}"`?

Comment: not working!! it's not even getting compiled. when I bind text it knows that I'm writing code, not a string but for ontextchanged XML doesn't recognize the code. @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but my suggestion was to change from `viewmodel.onEmailChanged` to `viewmodel.onEmailChanged(s)` just in case, since the first way (i.e., your way) obviously won't work. `onEmailChanged` is a method and should be invoked as such – the code you use in binding expressions is basically Java code.

Comment: I would consider doing [two-way binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) here instead of invoking a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use [two-way binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) with a `LiveData` property?

First, add the new `email` property to your viewmodel and subscribe to it to receive the changes:

```
class LoginViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val email = MutableLiveData<String>()

    // This observer will invoke onEmailChanged() when the user updates the email
    private val emailObserver = Observer<String> { onEmailChanged(it) }

    init {
        email.observeForever(emailObserver)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        email.removeObserver(emailObserver)
    }

    fun onEmailChanged(newEmail: String) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

Then, update the view to create a two-way binding between the `EditText` and the property `email` of your viewmodel:

```xml
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="@={viewModel.email}" />
```

Thanks to the two-way binding, whenever the user updates the text in the view, your viewmodel property will update (and vice versa).

This should hopefully do the trick!